# Absolute value of infinite series sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

How does it come about that 
$$\left|\Sigma_{n=-N}^{N}c_n(f)e^{inx} - \Sigma_{-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n(f)e^{inx}\right| = \left|\Sigma_{|n|>N} c_n(f)e^{inx}\right|?$$ What happens with the $n$-index? Could someone please show steps involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left|\Sigma_{n=-N}^{N}c_n(f)e^{inx} - \Sigma_{-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n(f)e^{inx}\right| &= \left|-\Sigma_{-\infty}^{-(N+1)} c_n(f)e^{inx}-\Sigma_{N+1}^{+\infty} c_n(f)e^{inx}\right|\\
&=\left|-\left(\Sigma_{-\infty}^{-(N+1)} c_n(f)e^{inx}+\Sigma_{N+1}^{+\infty} c_n(f)e^{inx}\right)\right|\\
&=\left|\Sigma_{|n|>N} c_n(f)e^{inx}\right|.
\end{align*}

As you can see, you are essentially removing the 'center' (around $0$) of the infinite summation. You then combine both terms by noting that $|-n|=|n|>N$ by using the clever notation $|n|>N$.

Comment: Just to confirm, does $|n|>N$ imply that $-N > n > N$? I.e. $(-\infty < n < -N) \cup (N < n < \infty)$.

Comment: @sequence Yes, exactly.